# Karate-UI Automation - Not able to click the elements using xpath

Tags: karate

I am not able to click the below particular XPath through karate syntax. Please let me know if i missed anything.

```
   When driver.click("(//div[@class='button-wrapper box']//button[@type='button'])[1]")
   And driver.click("(//div[@class='button-wrapper box']//button[@type='button'])[3]")
```

Error

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: karateUI.feature:37 - javascript evaluation failed: driver.click("(//div[@class='button-wrapper box']//button[@type='button'])[1]"), js eval failed twice:(//div[@class='button-wrapper box']//button[@type='button'])[1].click(), 

error: {"type":"object","subtype":"error","className":"SyntaxError","description":"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input","objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":1,\"id\":3}"}
```

Comment: help us replicate the problem, see this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/993

Comment: Looks like the last array addresses `[1]` and `[3]` should be places before the last closing `)`.